# Return JSON data from PHP script using AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Goal of Project: User enters in the serial number of a computer, the number is checked and if it matches a computer in our Airtable base, we add some information to it and create a new entry for it in a different tab.

My experience: I have lots of experience in Java, C, data structures and algorithms from University.  Before starting this project, I had zero experience in web development and have thus far attained basic knowledge of html, php, css, and js.

What I need help with: My current mini goal for the project is to have the user enter a serial number and have the computer information displayed on the same page.  I have my files shown below.  My process.php accurately retrieves the computer information given a serial number and converts it to a JSON object.  My my_script.js is what I used with my test.php to practice displaying the user input without redirection or page refresh.  My myform.html I believe is pretty self explanatory, just a form to take in a serial number.  I understand how my code in my_script.js works but need help adjusting it to handle JSON return.  Any help, resources or overall ideas about the project will be greatly appreciated.

myform.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Computer swap form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "test.php" id="computerForm">
Serial Number: <br>
<input name="serialnumber" type="text">

<button id = "sub"> Submit </button>
</form>
<!--display the response returned after form submit -->
<span id ="result"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my_script.js

```
$("#computerForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(info) {
    $("#result").html(info);
  });
});
```

process.php

```
<?php

include('./Airtable.php');
include('./Request.php');
include('./Response.php');

use \TANIOS\Airtable\Airtable;
$airtable = new Airtable(array(
    'api_key' => '***',
    'base'    => '***'
));
  //$sn = $_POST['serialnumber'];
    $sn = "a_serial_number"; //manual setting this produces correct info
  $params =  [
   "filterByFormula"=>"AND({S/N} = '$sn')"
];
$request  = $airtable->getContent('Computers', $params);
$response = $request->getResponse();
$data     = $response['records'];

echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$sn = $_POST['serialnumber'];

if(!isset($sn))
{
    echo "error serial number not set";
}
else {
    echo "$sn successfully saved";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use JSON.parse() to parse out your info from the JSON string and use it as an object or an array.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting it? How to display the information?

Comment: It's not clear to me how test.php and process.php are related.  Your ajax call is calling test.php, which is not doing anything with process.php

Comment: @JordanS He means what does he need to change when he sends the AJAX request to `process.php` instead of `test.php`.

Comment: @Taplar They're not related. He's evolving the code. He used `test.php` for a simple test, now he wants to change to `process.php` to get the real data from the API.

Comment: Adjust as in I want process.php to take in the serial number from the form, use it to call the airtable base and retrieve the information, and display that information to the user on the myform.html page

Comment: So change the `action` in your form to the correct URL and handle the response as you need to handle it. I'm failing to see the issue? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Are you going to be calling process.php directly, or are you going to be calling test.php, and including process.php if the serialnumber is on the request?

Comment: I included the test.php interaction as a means to communicate where my ability is currently at.  I've learning this on the fly in hopes of making a semi useful tool for my work.  I am sure that it not too complicated of a question but I really don't know a ton about this.  I am confused on how to change my code to handle a json return

Comment: Then do like Magnus said and change your script to call `process.php`.  You are already echoing the encoded json, so that's what the endpoint will get, and then do what Ryan Wilson said to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a `"json"` argument to `$.post` to tell it that the response is JSON, and it will automatically parse the response to a Javascript object or array. In my sample code below I'm assuming it's an array, and each element is an object that contains a property that you want to show in the result; replace `.someProperty` with the actual property.

```
$("#computerForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(info) {
    var html = "";
    $.each(info, function() {
        html += this.someProperty + "<br>";
    });
    $("#result").html(html);
  }, "json");
});
```

`process.php` can use `$_POST['serialnumber']` when it's calling the Airtable API.

```
$sn = $_POST['serialnumber'];
```

Comment: This worked for me!  If you don't mind I have a followup question.  The JSON return is set up as such:  [{"id":"xxx","fields":{"Name":"xxx",,"Location":"xxx","Model":"xxx",""S\/N":"xxx"},"createdTime":"xxxxx"}]       when replacing `this.someProperty` with `this.id`, the correct id is shown but I'm not sure how to display information within fields.  I figured it was another dot operator such as `this.fields.name` but this did not work

Comment: Nvm, it is the dot operator.  Thanks for you answer, Barmar!

Comment: Close, it's `this.fields.Name`